# Absolutely nothing changes when I deploy to Laravel Forge

Tags: php, laravel, server

I've been trying all afternoon to debug something on my prod server.

I've tried everything I can think of, including uninstalling the repo and grabbing a fresh copy from Bitbucket

I've cleared my browser cache about a gazillion times, used incognito windows etc.

When I SSH into the server I can see that my files are being pushed up, they just aren't changing anything in the browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else finds this, and they have an SSL certificate installed, check the cache settings of your SSL provider.

For me, it turned out Cloudflare was caching the site. I turned on developer mode in Cloudflare and my caching issues disappeared!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have OPCache turned on in your server PHP settings? Add this line to your deploy script to clear the cache on each deploy.

```
echo "" | sudo -S service php7.1-fpm reload
```

Comment: yarp, i do, here's my deploy script:

cd /home/forge/mydomain.com
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
echo "" | sudo -S service php7.1-fpm reload

if [ -f artisan ]
then
    php artisan migrate --force
fi

Comment: Try adding these artisan commands to it `php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan view:clear`

Comment: i also did that before I uninstalled and reinstalled the repo, i also ssh'd and removed everything from storage manually, i also added php artisan config:clear

Comment: ok so i just refreshed the page and my changes were live! after a couple hours... anyway I made a couple more changes, pushed and deployed and....nothing has changed again!!

Answer (score 0):

Based upon what you said, I assume your symlink is pointing to the previous commit. Make sure your symlink is pointing to the latest commit which you just deployed.

Comment: How do I find that out?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is what fixed it: `npm run build`

It wasn't about OPCache, Cloudflare, Forge or any of the other issues I spent hours investigating. I finally tried simply changing the site title and when that worked, I figured out the JavaScript in my public/build/assets file was not changing. I ran `npm run build` and it updated it - deployed and it worked.

I suspect this means I need to add `npm run build` to my deploy pipeline.